# Dynamic header bar/navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey im trying to create a dynamic header/ navigation bar such as the header bar seen here: http://www.feed-the-beast.com/

i currently have this to go with:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var lock = $('#header').position().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(lock >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
        if($('#header').hasClass('fixed')) {
            $('#header').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    } else { 
        if(!$('#header').hasClass('fixed')) {
            $('#header').addClass('fixed');
        }
    }
}); 
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="header" class=""></div>
```

Css:

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-color: #000;
left:0;
right: 0;
margin-top: 340px;
position: absolute;}

body {
height: 7000px;
width: 100%;
float: right;}
.fixed {
position: fixed;}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a sticky meniu with an anchor on scroll ?

Here is the script for it :

```
$(function() {
    var move = function() {
       var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        var ot = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
        var s = $("#scroller");
       if(st > ot) {
            s.css({
                position: "fixed",

            });
        } else {
            if(st <= ot) {
                s.css({
                    position: "relative",

                });
            }
        }
    };
    $(window).scroll(move);
    move();
});
```

And you need to add this to your HTML :

```
<div id="scroller-anchor></div>
   <div id="scroller">
     YOUR MENU HTML HERE
   </div>
```

**UPDATE**

A working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/vdA8x/2/) here :D

PS: Also, if you do not want your background color to change when it sticks to top, you only have to change `"background-color": "red"` with your desired background color.

Comment: When ever i use this script when i scroll down from the top the header dissapears.

Comment: The header is the one you want to place your menu in, right ? Wait just a second, I'll try and make it custom

Comment: Check out my update, just added a working jsFiddle for you with your provided code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vdA8x/4/ if the position is change to remove the white spaces on either side it sticks to the top.

Comment: That's cause you use ABSOLUTE positioning for both the blank content AND the menu, that places them one over another cause **position:absolute** is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use the positioning attributes **top** (instead of margin-top), **left**, **bottom** and **right** to set the location. but I don't recommend that, the blank_content should be position:relative;

Comment: ALSO, if you want to use position:absolute, the **top** or **margin-top** needs to be equal to the height of the blank_content in order to place it directly under it.